# Sum in nested loops returning incorrect

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, nested-loops

Not sure what is wrong here but I am trying to add a set of numbers in an array (not the whole array) but it looks like it is summing up the whole array:

```js
function sumPrimes(num) {
  var arr = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];
  var total = 0;
  var index;
  //loop through the whole array
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //find matching prime number
    if (num < arr[i]) {
      // get index of prime number in the array
      index = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);
      //sum up total of prime numbers up to 'num'
      for (var b = 0; b < index; b++) {
        total = total + arr[index];
      }
    }
  }
  return total;
}
sumPrimes(10);
```

Comment: please add some use cases, or at least add the wanted result.

Comment: `index = arr.indexOf(arr[i]);` - isn't that just an obfuscated way of saying `index = i`

Comment: console.log() is your friend to help you debug.

Comment: it's not adding the whole array, it's adding parts of the array multiple multiple times

Comment: because your second loop is inside the first.... So every iteration you loop again and again. Why you loop a second time makes no sense, just add up until you get to the number.

Comment: What is that you want to do here? Is that the sum of 10 prime numbers (or) sum of prime numbers come before 10 (i.e. 2,3,5,7) ?

Comment: I am actually trying to count the sum of the values of the array up to the index count. so for this example it should count from 2 up to 11

Comment: `arr.reduce((prev, curr, idx) => idx < num ? prev + curr : prev)`

Comment: thanks @JaromandaX. index=i is a much cleaner way than what I had

Comment: You should add expected results to your `sumPrimes(10)` call. There is counting elements in an array, and there is summing elements in an array, and then there is counting sums of elements in an array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to **calculate the sum of all prime numbers less than the given number**, then the solution is much easier.

Either

```
function sumPrimes(num) {
    var arr = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

    var total = 0;

    for (var x of arr) {
        if (x < num)
            total += x;
        else
            break;
    }

    return total;
}
```

which works when **arr** is sorted, or

```
function sumPrimes(num) {
    var arr = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97];

    var total = 0;

    arr.forEach(function(x) {
        if (x < num)
            total += x; 
    }, this);

    return total;
}
```

that would work for an unsorted array as well.

Comment: thanks, but I am actually trying to count the sum of the values of the array up to the index count. so for this example it should count from 2 up to 11

Comment: @sammyb123 that's exactly what my code does - it sums the numbers from 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17. Or do you mean need to sum up the first 10 numbers?

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace index with b:

```
//sum up total of prime numbers up to 'num'
for(var b=0; b<index; b++){
    total = total + arr[b];
}
```

EDIT: and get rid of the outer loop

Comment: Still will be wrong, you are correct it should be `b`, but there is another issue

Comment: and get rid of outer loop

Comment: how will index be set if you get rid of the outer loop?

Comment: you don't need index, i is the index